# .NET5 C# XPath Filter 2.0 Support (XML Digital Signatures)

Tags: c#, xml, digital-signature, .net-5

I'm writing a .NET5 routine to check a signed XML File. The file had this "http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" as transformation Alghoritm. So, when I try to load it into SignedXML object  (using SignedXml.LoadXml() method), I get an error:

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Unknown transform has been encountered.'

I tried to search for the correct transform class into .NET but i found only XmlDsigXPathTransform. Is there a way to achieve it?
Many thanks for your suggestions.

Check the XML signature

Comment: .NET 5 reached End Of Life 1 year ago. The Long Term Support version is .NET 6, supported until 2024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [System.Security.Cryptography.Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) namespace does not contain a class that implements the [XPath Filter 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-filter2-20021108/) transform algorithm, but only the [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116) transform algorithm (which is not the same).

A possibility would be to implement the XPath Filter 2.0 algorithm as a class inheriting from [Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.transform) yourself.